# How to style audio player?

Tags: css

I am trying to style a audio player that generates when the user clicks a music file.

In developer tool in chrome, the structure is like the following

```
<embed src='music.wav' >
    #document
        <html>
            <body>
                <video controls autoplay name='media'>
             <source src='music.wav' type='audio/x-wav'>
        </video>
        <body>
    <html>
</embed>
```

How do I style the video player that chrome generated in this case?? Thanks a lot!

Comment: any reason you're using the video tag to play an audio file?

Comment: what other choices do I have??

Comment: my project is not using html5. and audio tag is for html5 only.